# Does Amazon RDS support SQL Transaction Logs?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, sql-server-2008-r2, rds

Does Amazon RDS (sql-server) support sql transaction logs? if so

How can i enable it through RDS interface?
How can i access it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have automated snapshots turned on, then you can see it through the AWS RDS interface under DB Snapshots Automated.  You can choose to do automated backups when setting up the DB.  http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/ under Automated Backups and Database Snapshots it talks more about this procedure.

What I don't know is how to enable automated backups after creating the db.

Comment: Actually http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2933 contains details in Step 6 on how to turn on automated backups for an instance already live.  I have not tried this myself but would imagine it would work.